# Parameter contravariance not applied when function type is pulled from another type

Tags: typescript

I am confused about a situation in which I think TypeScript should raise an error, but doesn't. I get the error I am looking for when the function types are written out explicitly, however the error is not present when those types are pulled from another type, even though they resolve to the same thing.

See the following snippet:

```
type Foo = {
  getData(s: string): string;
}

type Bar = {
  getData(s: "bar"): string;
}

declare let all: Foo['getData'];
declare let lim: Bar['getData'];

all = lim // No error here
lim = all

declare let all2: (s: string) => string;
declare let lim2: (s: "bar") => string;

all2 = lim2 // Error Here
lim2 = all2
```

Error:

> Type '(s: "bar") => string' is not assignable to type '(s: string) => string'.
> Types of parameters 's' and 's' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"bar"'

I would expect to see this error on both assignments, but I only see it on the `all2 = lim2` assignment and not the `all = lim` assignment. So the questions are:

- why does this error only appear for the latter assignment and not the first?

But mainly:

- **How can I modify this to disallow the first assignment?**

Note: The `strictFunctionTypes` option *is enabled*.

---

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3sGMDmUQAiAhiEQBQDOAXDBSAE4CWAdjgJQ11OsDcwAvsFCRYAISL1UGLLnzFSlGgCIARhKUdaDFjj6DgAEygBjADYTYp-DCKnTNRAgDaAcjyESRFwF0%20RsxYwViBBjAC2NOL0ru7yXr5CtqZSpuHAqWFSSUL%205vSW1kkATDSKWtzsqAB85Tp%20JnkFIRklMGWq6mzVtbyJdkUp4UXpQ1n9wEA)

Comment: Methods are always exempt from strictfunctiontypes, as described in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types).  The "methodness" sticks with it, even if you use index access types to extract it.  Could you clarify which of your two bulleted questions is the [primary one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366)?

Comment: Thanks for that link, so methods are exempt, fair enough. The second of the two questions is the primary question though, is there any way I can change this to get the first assignment to produce an error (ideally without moving the function signature outside of the object type)?

Comment: Since your second question is the primary one, could you [edit] the question to make that    clear?  By the way, the answer might be "you can't do this", depending on use cases.  My hope was that you could "de-method" the type with conditional type inference, but it doesn't seem to work consistently ([link](https://tsplay.dev/Wk0nLw)).  Something about variance markers through aliases not behaving as I'd expect.  ‍♂️